# Get all records of n groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with multiple Paths of shares i want the get all the paths where the first N different Servernames in these Paths as example here the whole table.

```
+----+--------------------------------+
| ID | BACKUPPATH                     |
+----+--------------------------------+
|  1 | //server.domain/share/folder   |
|  2 | //server.domain/share/folder3  |
|  3 | //server.domain/share/folder2  |
|  4 | //server2.domain/share/folder1 |
|  5 | //server2.domain/share/folder2 |
|  6 | //server3.domain/share/folder1 |
|  7 | //server3.domain/share/folder2 |
|  8 | //server3.domain/share/folder3 |
+----+--------------------------------+
```

the Servernames could vary each time and the number the different Servenames could vary too. As example i want to get all Paths of the first 2 different Servernames i expect as Result:

```
+----+--------------------------------+
| ID | BACKUPPATH                     |
+----+--------------------------------+
|  1 | //server.domain/share/folder   |
|  2 | //server.domain/share/folder3  |
|  3 | //server.domain/share/folder2  |
|  4 | //server2.domain/share/folder1 |
|  5 | //server2.domain/share/folder2 |
+----+--------------------------------+
```

as subquery i use the following query to get rowset of the Servernames:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(BACKUPPATH,'/',3) as SERVERNAMES from(select BACKUPPATH from Backuppaths GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(BACKUPPATH,'/',3))as NUMEROFSERVERS LIMIT 2;

+------------------+
| SERVERNAMES      |
+------------------+
| //server.domain  |
| //server2.domain |
+------------------+
```

i am stuck now in how to use this subquery to get the results i expect.

Thanks for any help in this

Answer (score 1):

You can join to inline view:

```
select s.*
  from servernames s
  join (select substring_index(backuppath, '/', 3) as servername
          from servernames
         group by servername
         order by min(id) limit 2) v
    on substring_index(backuppath, '/', 3) = v.servername
 order by id
```

`Fiddle:` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6a16/1/0

Comment: You should use a `group by` in the subquery instead of distinct:  `group by servername order by min(id) limit 2`.  The OP asks for the first two server names.

Comment: @TReisser . . . You should accept Brian's answer if this works perfectly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Distinct`

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(BACKUPPATH,'/',3) AS SERVERNAMES FROM Backuppaths LIMIT 2;
```